# UITableViewCell keeps getting deselected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a strange problem with UITableView:
My tableview shows the names of objects from which the user can select one. The value is saved. When the tableview comes up the row is selected (in cellForRowAtIndexPath). But in viewWillAppear the row is first selected and then deselected. You can see that it is first selected because of a the blue background occurs for a short time.

I have set

> self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

but that does not work ether. Can someone help me out please! Thanks in advance.

Here some sample code:

```
#import "ECTESTTableViewController.h"

@interface ECTESTTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ECTESTTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 8;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        //        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"select %d", indexPath.row);
        cell.selected = TRUE;
    }
    else {
        //        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selected = FALSE;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: you mean you want to keep selected row with blue background ??

Comment: no, just the info which cell is selected. Mike answer was correct and fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to programatically select a row in a `UITableView` use:

`- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition`

Don't be setting the `selected` states of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Write following code

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work for me. [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] was nil. The cell.selected in cellForRowAtIndexPath didn't do the selection correct.